# Grant all privileges to my localhost MySQL account from a Google Cloud SQL MySQL so that I can migrate my local DB to the cloud one

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm currently trying to grant access to my locally hosted MySQL user to my Google Cloud SQL MySQL instance so that I can migrate a database over.

Currently, I've done the following:

Authorized my IP (it's from my ISP so it will change eventually) on my Cloud SQL connections.

On my laptop I've signed into my instance with:

```
mysql --host=12.345.678.90 --user=root --password
```

Then I created myself a user so that I can use `mysqladmin` and `mysqldump` to migrate the DB after.:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'andrew'@'98.76.543.210' IDENTIFIED BY 'andrew';
```

Then:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'andrew'@'98.76.543.210 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But I get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: So, just so we're clear... 12.345.678.90 is your Cloud SQL instance, and 98.76.543.213 is the local instance? So from your laptop, you're logging into your Cloud SQL instance, and creating a user that's authorized from your house to the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: And to confirm, if you go into the Cloud console (console.cloud.google.com), navigate to Cloud SQL, and click on your instance, then click on "Users" in the navigator on the left, do you see `root` there with `% (any host)` as the Host name?

Comment: You can use ["GRANT ALL ON `%`.*"](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#grantall) instead of "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES" which will grant all privileges, except SUPER and FILE as explained in the response posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Users created using Cloud SQL have all privileges except FILE and SUPER.

The set of privileges you can set are as below

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE ON mydb.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

So that is to say you cannot do GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES since it requires SUPERROLE.